# Continuing Education PhD

Tags: phd, united-states

With TA/RA stipends continuing to decrease relative to CoL, I'm wondering if there is any ongoing work to open up more PhDs with a continuing education model? I know some companies basically do this(Raytheon is one of them) where a relevant industry problem is being worked on and selected for PhD which the companies fund(and the person gets payed their standard salary for working on).

Some professors I have talked to resist this idea because they want academic purity but I suspect in the coming years that purity isn't going to be funded any longer.

Comment: Your premise is wrong.  This does happen and has happened for a long time.  It does not happen much because companies provide little funding for it.  It's not hard to find a university that will take the money.  Some governments offer matching funds for companies.

Comment: This seems to be highly specific to a particular country (USA?). Please be specific about what national context you talk about.

Comment: What is TA/RA? What is CoL?

Comment: Your monthly stipend vs cost of living. I live in place with 1k rent and a stipend of 1.7k. it's a huge monetary loss to continue a PhD program vs entering into industry.

Comment: You might want to be more specific about the field because this question doesn't make any sense in some

Answer (score 4):

(This answer is of course exaggerated, but it does contain a grain of truth.)

If you think carefully about the dynamics from the professors' point of view, then the answer is obvious.

Professors almost always make less money and generally have less research support than people working in industry.  This means, if someone becomes a professor, they are not interested in applied research and don't care that much about money.

Why would a professor agree to advise a student doing applied research?  They don't care about the research, and they don't care enough about the money for that to be an inducement.

From the other side, why would someone doing applied research even bother getting a PhD?  They can do their research without the degree, and if you've proven you can do the research, the diploma isn't really worth anything.

Conclusion: People become monks or starving artists for reasons of their own, and doing a PhD or becoming a professor is no different.  If society doesn't want to fund pure research or general education, then the natural dynamics will push universities towards becoming quasi-monastic institutions.  Remember that, in all the oldest European universities, their first professors were monks who were bound by vows of poverty.

(Note: Adjusted for inflation, my salary as a tenured professor is less than what I made before grad school in technology consulting.  My backup plan had I not gotten a professor job was peace activist, and most definitely not going back into tech.  Obviously I'm not in it for the money.)

Comment: There is vested national interest in graduating PhDs but I agree the model will need to change and be forced to conform to applied topics/working professionals. I would probably cut all university funding unless it translated to working systems which were in commerical development but at the same time pay way higher wages for working on these applied topics. Basically pay industry salary.

Comment: "I would probably cut all university funding unless it translated to working systems which were in commerical development" - uhh, then you basically don't have universities anymore. I suppose one can argue for this but you're suggesting something far more than a tweak to funding models by suggesting the end of higher education.

Comment: You have a university without the fat, exactly what is going to be needed.

Comment: @FourierFlux: You are suggesting a technology institute, not a university.  The prototypical subject for a university ought to be philosophy, even if philosophy has now splintered off into many fields.

Comment: I don't agree, the institutes I have been to don't really reach the theoretical level to do applied research. If you want to divide the universities into two groups, applied vs not I would be OK with that. All the funding will go to the applied group though, I guarantee it.

Comment: This is fundamental not great for science.  The reason NSF exists, the reason the US was top for research and new technology was our investment in theoretical work For example, people spent decades working on optimization methods that couldn't be used because the computational power wasn't available.  It was that work that allowed data science to take off so quickly because all the theory was there.  The difference between universities and industry is this constraint.  Are you hunting to create knowledge or hunting to create something that makes money.

Comment: I can't agree on data science, I am in ML and 90% of work is empirical. By that I mean the theory could have not been developed and nothing would have changed. Mainly because theoretical models make so many assumptions which are mostly invalid. This is a general trend in science.

Comment: This is one of the things we try to teach our students (even applied statisticians like myself). As ML becomes popular, people are using models where the assumptions under which the model were developed are not met. This is a problem because decisions are being made based on models that were not developed for that use; resulting in LOTS of bias/volatility. I believe this is the purpose of the PhD for those in industry, how do we appropriatedly use models with messy real life data. So I disagree with your statement, the theory allows it to be used, lack of understanding results in its misuse.

Comment: This is completely wrong, there is basically no theory behind deep learning computer vision and it's widely used in industry, it's literally the only technique that works. Areas like learning theory are mostly put in the garbage now, nobody cares and it doesn't really matter ultimately because at the end of the day everything is empirically driven. Basically theoreticians are kind of irrelevant.

Comment: @FourierFlux: And this is why you end up with algorithms that are racist.

Comment: Numerical solutions for Naiver Stokes approximations have(and continue to be used) under conditions which existence isn't even clear yet jets aren't crashing. In fact theoretical analysis of Naiver Stokes are mostly irrelevant to industry and everything still works because engineering and science are empirical in nature. Theory has marginal value and will never be able to take on complex problems. Every professor I have talked to both in DL and RL basically agree with this statement - people spend years chasing highly reduced approximations and barely prove something, mostly irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

I know some programs that do part-time PhDs in this specific scenario.  I don't know if schools with deeper pockets would do this anytime soon though.  Normally, profs will just get contract work to also fund their PhD students and the students will intern there in the summer (and still be able to work on their research project at higher pay).  Also, there are programs like ORISE that you can get paid like a regular gov't employee and get to do research at the same time.  But yes I agree, I think there will need to be more creative ways to help students get liveable wages.

Comment: Thanks, on very practical grounds spending 3-4 years on a PhD after masters while letting go of 90k+ salary+ work experience is exceedingly hard to justify unless you want to be a professor. Many PhD students in the US are foreign in part because their alternative wages are so much lower in their home country so universities can basically exploit them.

Comment: I agree but that's kind of the point. There really isn't a reason to get a PhD unless you want to be a researcher.   Most industry work ( with some exceptions) won't really pay a PhD that much more than someone with a MS.

Comment: There is research in industry

Comment: Yes, there is but its not the same type of research.  As aforementioned in comments, it will be focused on a product that can make money (with a few exceptions of course). In academia, you can pursue a topic for the sake of creating knowledge/contributing to the field.